# $\int_{0}^{x}t^{-1} \ln(1+2t)\ \mathrm{d}t$ as a power series

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Evaluate $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}t^{-1} \ln(1+2t)\ \mathrm{d}t$ as a power series. I think this is can be related to $\displaystyle\ln(1+x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ when $|x|<1$, so I think I can somehow utilize this as the power series expansion. What should I do next?

Comment: What is $t_{-1}$?

Comment: If $t_{-1}$ stands for $\frac 1t$,just go ahead with the series

Comment: $\frac{1}{t}\cdot\ln(1+2t)=\frac{1}{t}\cdot\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2t)^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2)^{n+1}t^n}{n+1}$,

$\displaystyle \int_0^x \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2)^{n+1}t^n}{n+1}dt$,

integrating term by term: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\displaystyle \int_0^x  \frac{(-1)^n(2)^{n+1}t^n}{n+1}dt = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2)^{n+1}x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}$, the bounds just need to be figured out for $x$